# How to detect the TIP of the triangle in image processing with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am currently working on a project which is image processing with OpenCV and one of its function is to detect the tip of the triangle. I want to detect ONLY the tip of the triangle, how can I detect and what algorithm is the best approach for this? [Here is the sample picture of the tip of the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebsbl.png)

Comment: That is kind of ambiguous, a triangle has 3 tips... not one, also, is the triangle always in the same position? do you mean the highest tip? what happens with a triangle that has the base on the top? post an image of the traingle . What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, what i mean is the highest tip of the triangle and i want to detect it no matter what is the position of the triangle. I've tried corner detection algorithms but it cannot accurately detect the tip. Image is already posted in the question

Answer (score 2):

You could try line detection in openCV (https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) to get the function representations of the edges of the triangle and search for the intersections of these lines.

Once you find the intersections you can calculate the angle between the lines and use a threshold angle value to choose which intersection is the tip you want.

Comment: Thankyou for the response :) but ill be positioning the camera 3-4 meters away from the triangle illustration, would getting the angle be accurate in that scenario sir?

Comment: @JGreat There will be some uncertainty in the angle threshold so you could specify a range. As i don't know what your illustration looks like (noisy?) and how large it is hard for me to say exactly how accurate, but i would assume you could get a fairly accurate value. Try it and see how your calculated value compares to the actual angle (measure it).